# visual editors for JSF

Tags: jsf

Could anyone suggest some free/commercial visual editors for JSF. I have tried Visual Web Plugin for Netbeans but was not much impressed.

Comment: Professionals don't use visual editors. They only generate unmaintainable code.

Comment: Anyone who have used Delphi professionally once in live knows it is not true. Delphi IDE have a God like visual editor that generates DFM files that are fully editable by hand and can be back on the editor without any loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Exadel Studio](http://www.exadel.com/exadelstudio/help/#jsf) is something to look at. [JBoss Developer Studio](http://www.jboss.com/products/devstudio/) as well.